# Placing a pre-comp inside another pre-comp in AfterEffects

Tags: adobe-after-effects

When creating complex animations I often use pre-composition to stack them and further animate them separately.

I am now facing two fully animated pre-comps and I need to place pre-comp**_1** inside pre-comp**_2**. Why? Cause pre-comp**_2** is a phone that also has environment reflections on it and pre-comp**_1** is the content that is shown on the screen, therefore I need to rearrange the layer order so the reflections are on top of pre-comp**_1**.

Is there a good way of doing this? Other than removing the reflections and stacking it on top of both pre-compositions?

[image]

**gif:**
*This is what I would like to achieve but obviously it's not working like that. I can't find a way to add pre-comp_1 under Reflection inside pre-comp_2 without loosing the animation I already have on the pre-comp*

[image]

Comment: Why is it a problem that you have nested pre-compositions. After effects is by the way the only compositioning app where you would care because it likes to show you things a s a stack. If you were to view your process as a network you wouldn't care too much eiter

Comment: @joojaa I care because there are times when I need to add a pre-composition as an item of another pre-composition. I have described exactly why I need to do this and I couldn't find anything that would let me do so.

Comment: Yes but i fail to see why placing comp inside comp inside comp iside a comp is a problem

Comment: @joojaa The problem is that if I already have two comps created with animations inside, like in my print-screen, I am not able to add **pre-comp_1** inside **pre-comp_2**. I can't find a way to add pre-comp_2 as a child of pre-comp_1.

Comment: Yes but there is no limit how many precomps or comps for that matter you can put inside precomps. the only limitation is that the comps can not become circular in nature. So if master comp includes precomp 2 and you want precomp 1 to be inside comp 2 open comp 2 and drag the comp 1 in place. The only limit is that they can not be circularily referenced. There is in issence no limitiation like you describe. But we can not debug this form your image since ist not showing what the precomps are like.

Comment: @joojaa , Added a gif in my question, maybe you can understand better what I am dealing with.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47052/discussion-between-joojaa-and-alin).

Comment: Why isn't it working? You can nest precomps as much as you like, there shouldn't be any reason you can't do what you want

Comment: @Cai well, adding the comp 1 inside comp 2 from the Project panel will 'erase'all the animation I have on the comp right now. Isn't there a way to simply drag the comp inside the other one and let it be?

Comment: as in animated properties on the composition itself (i.e not *inside* the composition)?

Comment: I'm sure it shouldn't erase those... hold on let me do a test

Comment: @Cai , it does, just tried it and talked about it with joojaa.

Comment: You can't drag and drop it from comp to comp but you can copy/paste and it keeps all keyframes etc. just tried it now

Comment: @Cai Well...that's...that's...:| THAT'S WAY TOO EASY TO THINK OF !!! :)) Oh come on, are you kidding me? I spent all my time looking for this and didn't think to just copy/paste the comp rather than moving it???

Comment: @Cai you might as well add it as an answer. No need to waste the bounty...I feel stupid.

Comment: Don't feel stupid, we all do it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't drag and drop between compositions but you can copy and paste an entire layer, and it will copy any animated keyframes along with it.

Take the following example. I have a main composition with two pre-comps. "Pre-comp 2" has animated position keyframes.

Select the "Pre-comp 2" layer (only the layer, no keryframes or anything) and copy.

[image]

Open "Pre-comp 1" and paste. See the position keyframes are copied with it.

[image]

Just remember to delete the original "Pre-comp 2" from the main composition.

Comment: Yeey!! Thanks, I still feel stupid though! :)

Comment: This is actually one of the hardest things to debug since the very fundamental first thing you should try has been missed. And its pretty hard to come up with the answer connect the power cable. ;)